# RewriteRule giving 404 with additional query parameters

Tags: .htaccess

I am using rewrite rules to make my URls SEO friendly and the following rule is working fine for products page.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^pid=([a-z0-9A-Z_\-]*)$
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ product/viewproduct.php?pid=%1&cat1=$1&cat2=$2 [L]
```

However, when I pass additional query parameters to product page (e.g. utm_source), It's returning a 404.

Please help.

Comment: and assuming you inspected that url with `utm_source` added, what are the results?

Comment: See if replacing `[L]` with `[L,QSA]` helps. (https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteFlags/QSA)

Comment: @kerbholz tried [L,QSA]. still giving 404. here is how my url looks like: 
 http://localhost/fruits/banana?pid=banana&utm_source=email

Comment: How do I inspect the url? It's just throwing a 404. Pardon my limited knowledge with PHP here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `RewriteCond` blocks to access to the `RewriteRule`.

Remove the `$` to access to your page and, add `,QSA` to access to your parameters.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^pid=([a-z0-9A-Z_\-]*)
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ product/viewproduct.php?pid=%1&cat1=$1&cat2=$2 [L,QSA]
```